# What is the surest way to authenticate (login) via HTTP?

Tags: http, security, authentication, ssl

First of all, I am sorry for my bad English.

I am writing an app with a backend, which I want to make safe. I am using HTTPS for the connection, but a lot of people say that this is not enough protection.

At the moment, my user credentials are sent to the server via JSON format as plain text, which isn't a good way, I guess. At the server, my password is hashed with a random salt and stored in the database.

If the login is successful, an authentication token is generated and sent to the client. The client is using it as a header.

Do I need to do more? I read something about digest access authentication. Should I implement this authentication method, or is there a better way to make my login safe? Or is this the right place to use this authentication method?

Comment: *"Do I need to do more?"* - Impossible to say. It depends on how important the security is. In many cases, your approach would be enough. But not all of them.

Comment: I should be really safe. So do you know something about digest access authentification? Is this a possible approach for a login? And how much safer would it become?

Comment: More information about digest access authentication can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), however beware that this was designed to be used on HTTP and as the wiki states "Because of the disadvantages of Digest authentication compared to Basic authentication over HTTPS it has been deprecated by a lot of software"

Comment: Digest access authentication is something defined in the HTTP standard however, it might be more wise to create your own implementation of it, might also be more secure